# proxying ip from nginx to jetty/gwt

Tags: nginx, proxy, ip-address, jetty, gwt

Good morning!

I have nginx setup in front of jetty 6, which is running a GWT application.  I am trying to forward the ip address, and all the answers I find on the internet tell me to do this:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

This works just fine, except that jetty's logs don't show the X-Real-IP, they show 127.0.0.1.  Also, jetty/GWT has 127.0.0.1 for `getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr()`, although I can access the X-Real-IP to get the correct remote IP.

Any ideas how to get the correct remote ip for the jetty logs and also get `getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr()` to work correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add forwarded config to your connector in /etc/jetty.xml. Example:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
           <Set name="forwarded">true</Set>
```

This should work.

Comment: In todays version of jetty by doing this I'm getting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector